# What is output of console.timeEnd()

Tags: javascript

#### Code

```js
console.time();
// ---
console.timeEnd();

// output
default: 72.081ms
```

Here, what is `ms`? is it microseconds or milliseconds?

I didn't get anything from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/timeEnd

Comment: Microseconds would generally be abbreviated μs so this is milliseconds.

Comment: Please take a look into [timer-table](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#timer-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ms means **milliseconds**.

console.time() -> starts a timer

console.timeEnd() -> ends a timer.

- By using them together you can measure how long does it take to perform an operation.

E.g.

```js
console.time();
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  // long time process
}
console.timeEnd();
```